# update system variable in windows for JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, windows

I have installed Java on my Windows 7 machine. Next, I added the user variable `JAVA_HOME` in environment variables, and put `JAVA_HOME` into the `path` variable, like so:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

When I run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` from the command line, I get `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17`. And, when I run `echo %path`, I get:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DNASTAR\SeqMan NGen 3;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePas
s 2011\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass 2011\;;C:\Program Files\Broadcom
\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Window
s\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerS
hell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI
 Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C
:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WH
L\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64
\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\S
ervices\IPT\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

However, when I try to run `javac` from the `bin` folder, I get the following error:

```
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What you get when you run `javac -version` on command prompt?

Comment: Ae you sure you have installed the JDK? If not, you have only java, not javac

Comment: Also, you want system variables, not user variables.

Comment: C:\Users\kavita85>java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the *PATH* of user variables

[image]

Comment: i don't have any path variable in user variable.

Comment: @p27 These are environmental varibales. Follow following links --->[Set the CLASSPATH environment variable](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/ece122/help/setenvironment.htm) and --->[How do I set or change the PATH system variable?](http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Comment: so,am i setting wrongly ?? and you want to say i will add java home like C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17 in path in place of %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: @p27 PATH must be located either under user or under system , please make sure to have _both_ JAVA_HOME and PATH under the same category and here you go :)

Comment: one up for your following comment:->please make sure to have both JAVA_HOME and PATH under the same category and here you go :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you running javac from a command prompt that was opened *after* creating the PATH entry? The reason I ask, is because a command prompt is initialized with the env variables that are present when it is *first* opened. After that, any changes made to the env variables won't be recognized by that command prompt. So if you did make a change, make sure to close the current command prompt and open a new one so it will see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the beginning of your `PATH` variable instead of at the end. Then open a new DOS prompt and try `java -version` again.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can run java, but not javac, I guess you have installed a JRE, which does not contain javac. You need to install the JDK.

Comment: When I run echo %JAVA_HOME% from the command line, I get C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17 this means i installed JDK.